# How to to transform x^(...) to x^{...} even when brackets are inside? Pure Regex possible?

Tags: php, regex

I need to change many posts and edit the content so that `^(...)` becomes `x^{...}`.

What I have so far:

```
    $regexpattern = "/\^\((.*?)\)/";
    $replaceregex = "^{\$1}";

    $content_new = preg_replace($regexpattern, $replaceregex, $content);
```

which works.

However, I realized that if there is a round bracket inside the round wrapping brackets, it fails.

Example:

```
this should be transformed a^(x²) and this b^(-(x²))
```

becomes:

```
this should be transformed a^{x²} and this b^{-(x²})
```

Needed:

```
this should be transformed a^(x²) and this b^{-(x²)}
```

How can I prevent this and only replace the last bracket? Or do we need to use PHP and explode the content with ^(...) into Arrays and replace?

It could also be that there are multiple brackets inside (even if rare).

PS: After writing this question I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052437/1066234 but there is no solution provided for this specific case.

Comment: Regular expressions typically have problems with all kinds of nested structures.

Comment: What is expected output for `this should be transformed a^(x²) and this b^(-(x²))`?

Comment: this recursive expression https://regex101.com/r/Hlt37z/2 seems to work don't know if recursive expression are supported by preg_replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such regex matches only outter brackets

```
 \^(\((([^()]|(?1))*)\))
```

and replace with

```
^{$2}
```

[**demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/tMlAzv/9)

[**demo on sandbox**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e5b3b5c9101bfc9b53d1c7069f537f094dd3078)

Comment: OP wants to match `^` before `(`

Comment: Worked nicely in my test: https://regex101.com/r/tMlAzv/10 (one line is a non-match on purpose)

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [recursive regex in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) with a negative lookahead:

```
$str = 'this should be transformed a^(x²) and this b^(-(x²))';
$re = '/\^ ( \( ( (?: [^()]* | (?-2) )* ) \) ) (?!.*\^\()/x';
$repl = preg_replace($re, '^{$2}', $str);
//=> this should be transformed a^(x²) and this b^{-(x²)}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U9HH3H/1)